# Execute the git describe command from jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am new to Jenkins. The idea is to have a git tag on the master branch.
Only by having a tag will we have the no_commits_since_last_tag number to set in the build number. The trick is to execute the git describe command from Jenkins in order to determine the tag number and the no commits number.

How could i execute git describe from Jenkins?

I am not shore if i can run this command. 
If i add a groovy script or a shell script (after build).

Following GIT plugins are installed:

[Git plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin)
[Git client plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Client+Plugin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a shell script 'after build' would suffice, a quick and dirty example:

```
last_tag=$(git describe)
echo $last_tag
```

you can the use the variable in any following logic.

Comment: Thank you for response. The form of the result is: + git describe 
+ last_tag=jenkins-job_name-762
+ echo jenkins-job_name-762
jenkins-job_name-762. This is the name of the job instead of tag name from GIT.

Comment: I tested with Putty, and it may be another problem. But if the result is the same as from command line, question is solved. Thank you.